Find max bytes in-flight when analyzing pcap
I got a pcap file and need to analyze and calculate max in flight bytes from server to client. It should be number of bytes has been sent but not yet received (ack) by other size right? I also need to handle edge case of out of order and drop packaged as well.
Here is what I've tried
from scapy.all import *

def max_in_fight(pcap_file):
   packets = rdpcap(pcapfile)

   # Hand shake
   p = packets.pop(0) # From client -> server
   srcInit = p[IP].src
   dstInit = p[IP].dst
   p = packets.pop(0) # Server ack
   p = packets.pop(0) # Client ack

   max_inflight = 0
   
   for packet in packets:
       # What should I calculate here???
       # Is it max(packet.seq, ) - max(packet.ack)???

   return max_inflight
   



